# Можно ли запустить javascript код canvas внутри pyqt5?

Tags: javascript, python, html, pyqt5, qwebengineview

Мне стало интересно можно ли запустить  `javascript`, 
который генерирует (работает с) `canvas` окном внутри *PyQt5*?

python

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        canvas_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        canvas_widget.setStyleSheet('background:red;')
        
        lay.addWidget(canvas_widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

javascript

```
var canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');

canv.width = window.innerWidth;
canv.height = window.innerHeight;

ctx.fillStyle = 'magenta'
ctx.fillRect(50,50,300,200)

ctx.arc(canv.width/2,canv.height/2,100,0,Math.PI)
ctx.fill()
```

Если да, то что мне для этого лучше всего сделать?
Что нужно скачать (подключить).

Желательно объяснить как можно более детально.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick  Я добавил небольшой код для примера

Comment: Можно всё сделать в html + javascript а отображать это через PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView

Comment: @Александр Я вроде бы ради эксперимента уже использовал `PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView` а точнее 
`QWebView` из `Qdesigner`. Вставил `html` из какой-то страницы. 
Но отоброзилось  только некоторые `html` тэги и немного `css`.
Меня волнует то какое количество команд и операций может поддерживать `PyQt5`. из
`html` `css` `js`. ведь даже браузеры разнятся в том что подерживать а что нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

то что предложил Александр, может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QDateTime, QUrl


html = """
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>background-image</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-image: url('file:///D:/_Qt/__Qt/image.jpg ');
        background-color: #c7b39b;               
      }
      p {
        color: #f00;
        font: bold italic 15pt 'Comic Sans MS';
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </body>
</html>
"""


def append():
    some_html = "<p>{}</p>".format(QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString())
    page.runJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML += '{}'".format(some_html)
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QWebEngineView()

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(append)
    page = view.page()
    page.loadFinished.connect(lambda: timer.start(1000))

    page.setHtml(html, baseUrl=QUrl('file://'))                   

    view.resize(512, 384)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]